# Robustness vs Generalization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, image-classification

I don't quite understand the difference between robustness and generalisability in relation to image processing (CNN). If my model generalises well, it is also robust to changes in the image material. Unfortunately, I haven't found any concrete definitions or other materials that describe the exact difference,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.00504.pdf). Its introduction gives a very good definition of both:

> The classic approach towards the assessment of any machine learning model
> revolves around the evaluation of its generalizability i.e. its performance on **unseen** test scenarios.

> Evaluating such models on
> an available non-overlapping test set is popular, yet significantly limited in its
> ability to explore the model’s resilience to **outliers and noisy data** / labels (i.e.
> robustness).

For generalizability, unseen data does not have to be noisy or contain more outliers compared to original data. You can simply split your original data set into 3: training, validation and test; use training and validation for the model development and keep test data unseen for a final check after cross validation. This will check your model's generalizability. Test set created in this way won't be more noise or have more outliers compared to the other two.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to answering the question is in light of the language industry leaders are using like Google and Facebook in their open-source and published papers. I also try to fill in the gaps when they contradict in terminology but present the same information.

## **Robustness**

Robustness as a term has been used by Google to refer to model performance on OOD (Out of Distribution) Data with Covariate or Subpopulation Shift [1]. Also in line with the previous answer, Facebook used Robustness to refer to model resilience to Adversarial Attacks [2]. Furthermore, Google to demo the robustness of their new model Pixel, 1- they presented the argument that it performs well on benchmark datasets of OOD and 2- on a colab notebook for plex_vit computer vision model practical demo [4], they used adversarial attacks with adding gaussian noise on images to demo its reliance to it like Facebook in [2]. Thus I conclude that there is a proposed assumption that model's with good OOD performance are also resilient to adversarial attacks. Robustness has also been described by Domain Adaptation by Facebook in their paper [5] where they measured Domain Adaptability by performance on OOD benchmarks datasets (Colored/Rotated MNIST, VLCS, PACS, Office-Home, Terra-Incognita, and DomainNet) much like Google did in [1] (except google called it Robustness). Thus, I think that Facebook used the term Domain Adaptation inaccurately to describe robustness in their paper [5].

In conclusion, in image classification at least, I think robustness is a model's ability to classify objects it was trained to in the training set in a noisy/or-not-noisy (pictures could be clean) OOD test set. In addition to classifying these objects in noisy images like blurred images for example (what I like to call model's resilience).

## **Generalization**

First, Domain Adaptation I think is a model's ability on learning classifying objects it was never trained on in the first place which is also google's description in [1]. Perhaps "Few-Shot", "One-Shot" and "Zero-Shot" training are the best terms for presenting Domain Adaptation. Generalization as mentioned in the previous answer means performance on unseen test scenarios. However, Google refers to model performance on unseen test scenarios of the same data set as a special case of generalization called In-Distribution generalization [3].

All in all, I think that Generalization is a broader term for Robustness, Resilience, and Domain Adaptation. From a Machine-Learning/AI engineering perspective though, a generalizable model is a reliable one that won't fail in production. Thus I think that Google in [1] and [3] instead of generalization, used the term "reliability" for that reason.

[1]https://ai.googleblog.com/2022/07/towards-reliability-in-deep-learning.html

[2]https://captum.ai/tutorials/CIFAR_Captum_Robustness

[3]https://goo.gle/plex-paper

[4]https://github.com/google/uncertainty-baselines/blob/main/experimental/plex/plex_vit_demo.ipynb

[5] https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.01434.pdf